# Add data lines file 2 to file 1 without header

Tags: text-processing

Here is my data: 
File1

```
Cow_ID  Age DIM MY  MCF MCP MCL BW  BCS
1   1424    0   NA  NA  0.0336  0.0505  NA  4.25
```

File 2:

```
Cow_ID  Age DIM MY  MCF MCP MCL BW  BCS
2   1424    0   NA  NA  0.0336  0.0505  NA  4.25
```

I want to add data from `file2` to `file1` but without the header. I am using this command but do not know how to remove the header before:

```
cat file2.txt>>file1.txt
```

Can you please help me to amend this code.

Comment: `man tail`, `man head`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several approaches:

```
tail -n +1 <file2 >>file1

sed -e 1d <file2 >>file1

awk 'NR > 1' <file2 >>file1
```